# Count the content of a column and show the total

Tags: php, mysql, count, numbers

(Sorry i dont know how this works to get it from the hold gone)

This is the mysql that i'm using for the code:

```
name    overall
Hi3     20,012
Hi2     3,396
Hi      16,498
```

And i want the following result
count all overall = 39906.

Is it possible to count the content from the table together and to show the result into digits?
Now i used the following :`$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(overallnow) FROM track")`

But i have no idea how i can show the result2. I hope Somebody can help me with this. I'm already trying to get this working for a few days.

Kev.

Comment: I really had no idea how i could get it of the "on hold".

Comment: Do your overall values really have a comma? What datatype is your overall column?

Comment: @MarkBaker Type = varchar(13) This because i have dont know mutch about mysql.

Comment: If you have problems with general MySQL access, have a look at the respective [documentation's example](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#example-1721).

Comment: @silkfire Thats working! but it only shows the numbers before the ,

Comment: Then you should really learn a bit more about SQL.... starting with the fact that MySQL has integer and float datatypes - sort your database out so that you can store numbers as numbers and it will make your life a lot easier... you can't use a MySQL SUM on string values with comma-thousands separators and expect to get a correct result, so it's making anything you do extremely difficult

Comment: @MarkBaker i will :) Is there in the meantime a easy solution for it?

Comment: There isn't an easy solution, only a complex one... and if you did implement a workaround, you'd simply never get round to fixing the underlying problem.... fix the underlying problem now

Comment: One dirty workround is to retrieve all three values, then loop through each, stripping the commas, and summing the resulting values manually in PHP.... slow, inefficient, dirty, and guaranteed to give you problems in the future.... the other workround (equally bad) is to use SUM(REPLACE(',','',overall))

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks then. I will be going to learning PHP and MYSQL then .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo array_pop(mysql_fetch_row($result2));
```

Yeah, my solution works if you have the right datatypes for your columns. In this case, the `overall` column should fittingly have the datatype `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.